# SAS get stock prices from internet (example Yahoo or Google Finance)

Tags: sas

I would like to connect to the internet to find stock prices for some stocks via SAS.

I found an example for connectioning to linkedin, but could not figure out how to do it for google finance or yahoo.

An example of what I want to do:
Connect to google finance or Yahoo Finance, and collect the closing price of a specific stock into my sas dataset.

Is this even possible in SAS?

Comment: Everything is possible, try `proc http`.

Comment: And if that doesn't work, try curl.

Comment: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Base-SAS-Programming/How-to-import-income-statement-info-from-Yahoo/m-p/303423/highlight/true#M64448

Comment: If you search on communities.sas.com there's several examples.